# How to display a minimization problem

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle

I want a space between `min` and `c` and I also want the `x>0` to be under the other lines, in the center. I have written this:

```
\begin{center}
$min c^{T}x\newline
     Ax = b\newline
     x\geq{0}
$
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: i don' t have errors in my code.

Comment: Put, please, `\min` instead of `min`. It is very nice because `\min` it is roman in mathmode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a dedicated package for the layout of optimisation problems: `optidef`, which allows for many variants. Here is an example of what can be done:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini}|s|[0]
    {x}{c^{T}x}
    {}
    {\label{eq:minimizationProblem}}{}
    \addConstraint{Ax}{= b}
    \addConstraint{x}{ \ge 0}
\end{mini}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I, for example, did not know the package that you have reported. +1 very elegant your answer. I thought he only wanted what he had reported in the code.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Your solution is quite nice (+1), but I thought I should show a variant layout with this possibility. The package is rather recent on CTAN – not even mentioned in the TeX Catalogue. It's part of MiKTeX and TeX Live, though.

Comment: In all honesty, I offer you my most heartfelt thanks. In almost two years of registration to this beautiful site I ask questions rarely difficult and I answer with extreme synthesis to those that I can do especially where it does not take so long. Thanks again. +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Μαρία,

Follows a suggested way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

τεστ

\[
\min c^{T}x
\]

\[
Ax = b
\]

\[
x\geq{0}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And how can i put this in the center of the page? I add the line \begin{center} but now it doesn`t work.

Comment: Welcome... Please not that math inside double dollars (`$$<math here>$$`) or better inside `\[` and `\]` willbe printed centered in their own line. between single dollars `$<math here>$` or better `\(` and `\)` will be printed inline. Also, for `min` there is a command from `amsmath` package that I used. But for non declared math commands you have to declare them via the tools of package and for other kind of spaces try `\,` and `\;` or `\quad` between math expressions.

Comment: Please run the code ρε Μαρία as it is... It is already centered.

Comment: κι έτσι το έτρεξα αλλά πάλι η στοίχιση είναι στ αριστερά.

Comment: Maria just run my code as it is provided with no extra commands... It will give all the equations centered. (Please keep the communication in English to respect non Greeks). If you have used some documentclass/template or other packages/commands that breaks these basic LaTeX features, please consider changing/removing  these documentclass/template or package/commands. I will add a photo of my output that should be yours too

Answer (score 2):

I will use for this type of construct the option `aligned`. The formula is centered.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
\min c^{T}x&\\
Ax= b &\\
x\geq{0}& \\
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```