# Equations are not aligning properly

Tags: align

I would like write my equations as shown in the figure. 
[image: Equation figure]

I have tried with *align* environment. But can't able to achieve it.

Here is what i have tried.

```
\begin{align}
min \quad c^T x \nonumber \\
s.t \quad Ax &= b \nonumber \\
\quad x \geq 0 \nonumber \\
\quad x \in Z^n \nonumber
\end{align}
```

The output i am getting like this:

[image: My output[2]]

Can somebody help me to fix the problem. Highly appreciated.

Comment: Here there is also a best answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457938/how-to-display-a-minimization-problem/457940#457940 for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put ampersands where you want the equations to align. The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

 \begin{alignat*}{2}
    \min        &\quad&   c^T x& \\
    \text{s.t. }&& Ax &= b \\
                &&  x &\geq 0 \\
                &&  x &\in Z^n \\
  \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Note also:

- use `alignat` to align more than "one column. The `&\quad&` inserts a `\quad` space
- the `*`  in `alignat*` means that you do not want equation numbers (so you don't need `\nonumber`)
- use `\min` instead of `min` (which looks likes `m*i*n`)
- use `\text{s.t. }` instead of `s.t.`

Comment: But how do `min` and `s.t.` get aligned?

Comment: @Tvde1 Ah, sorry, didn't notice that you wanted this too. Will edit.

Comment: @Tvde1 i too have same doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with the dedicated package `optidef`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}

\begin{document}

    \begin{mini*}
        {}{c^T x}
        {}{}
        \addConstraint{Ax}{ = b}
        \addConstraint{x}{\ge 0}
        \addConstraint{x}{\in Z^n}
   \end{mini*}

\end{document}
```

[image]